# Scheduling Report Error : Salesforce.com could not email the report to any of the specified recipients

Tags: administration, permissions, profile, custom-report-type

I have a create separate profile for a user who has the following set of permissions:

1. Schedule Reports
2. Manage Reports in Public Folders
3. Subscribe to Reports
4. Schedule Reports

The user is able to access a report folder called `Service Desk Reports` and run a report called `Open Service Requests`. However on scheduling this report, that user is getting following error in email :

> Salesforce.com could not email the report to any of the specified
>   recipients. Check that recipients are specified and that they have the
>   appropriate permissions to view the report.

Looks strange for me, Why user unable to get the scheduled report? What extra permissions do I need to give?

Please Note: When I manually shared the folder with the same user, he was able to get the scheduled report in email.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you add `View Reports in Public Folders` permission to that user's profile and let me know if that works for you

Comment: @SantanuBoral This particular permission we have given to the user already in profile level, He can see the record , can access it and also able to run the report .  Only thing he get error when report are scheduled.  he has schedule the report for next 1 hour , Instead of getting report in mail. above mentioned error we are getting during scheduling report.